# Cannot set a formControlName of an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form that has the following structure:

[image]

My goal is to set the formControlName of `serviceIsSelected` in HTML. This is what i have tried:

```html
@for (service of dataSource; track dataSource; let index = $index) {
  <h2>{{service[0].sectionTitle}}</h2>
  <table mat-table *ngIf="dataSource && dataSource[index]" [dataSource]="dataSource[index]" formArrayName="services">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="active">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
        {{ element.serviceIsSelected | json }}
        <mat-checkbox [formControlName]="element.serviceIsSelected"></mat-checkbox>
      </td>
```

`element.serviceIsSelected` returns *false*, which is the value of `serviceIsSelected`. My problem is the value of `formControlName`, which gives me the error:

> Error: Cannot find control with path: 'services -> false'

I also tried it with `formControlName="serviceIsSelected"`, but then I get the error:

> Error: Cannot find control with path: 'services -> serviceIsSelected'

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: If I squint at the picture, I see a `FormGroup` between `services` and `serviceIsSelected`...

Comment: 1. You are missing the `FormGroup` after the `services` FormArray. 2. You are binding the value to `formControlName`. Instead, you should do like this: `formControlName="serviceIsSelected" [value]="element.serviceIsSelected"`, or you should construct the `FormGroup` structure and setting the value in the component side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formArrayName="services"` is correct. However, this approach is not enough since it also includes a `FormGroup`.

```html
@for (service of dataSource; track dataSource; let index = $index) {
  <h2>{{service[0].sectionTitle}}</h2>
  <table mat-table *ngIf="dataSource && dataSource[index]" [dataSource]="dataSource[index]" formArrayName="services">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="active">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
        {{ element.serviceIsSelected | json }}
        <mat-checkbox formControlName="serviceIsSelected"></mat-checkbox>
      </td>
```